# jquery plugin Pace.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

i am using jquery plugin pace.js, and i want that when the page is load then first the progress bar is loaded after that the content will shown,
this is my code

```
<div class="pace  pace-inactive">
    <div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pace-activity"></div>
</div>
```

the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msz900/59caubpx/) will define the result of my work.

in my case the content and progress bar both will show simultaneously.

**What i want:** i want that first the progress bar will show and after the complition of progress bar the content will show like in [this](http://www.spab-rice.com/themeforest/pond/demo/index.html) website.

**Update:**

This is what i try next but when the progress is complete then it will not show any contents...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>bk</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pace-atom.css"/>
      <style>
         #contents {
             display: none;
         }
         .cover {
             position: fixed;
             left: 0px;
             top: 0px;
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
             z-index: 1999;
             background:rgb(33,33,33);
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body class="pace-done">
      <div class="pace  pace-inactive">
         <div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="pace-activity"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <div id="contents">
            <img src="d3.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="d1.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="d2.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="d2.jpg" alt=""/>
            <img src="d1.jpg" alt=""/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="js/pace.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
             Pace.on("done", function(){
                 $("#contents").fadeIn(1000);
             });
         }

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this out http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/16/caching-images-with-javascript-and-html5-progress-bars/

Comment: thanks for the link, but i am looking only for pace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so an easy way to implement this is to hide all your contents until pace is done loading (I assume there is a reasoning to pace's load screen but I'm not sure).

So your contents could have an id `#contents` and be default `display: none`. You can then show the contents after pace is done like so

```
$(function() {
    Pace.on("done", function(){
        $("#contents").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/59caubpx/3/

Comment: @webydesigny where in your html are you putting the JS? It has to be after the pace.js JS insert and ideally at the end of the page. On the fiddle the JS is executed on page load so try my edited answer. Other than that remember all your contents should be wrapped in a div with `id='contents` which has css set to `display: none`.

Comment: can you please tell me that how to reduce the progress speed? mean progress time, by default it run faster..

Comment: yes, i want to decrease the progress sped, so that the user see the loading screen for long time

Comment: I'm not sure how to extend loading times. I advise you look at the documentation: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/

Answer (score 14):

If the progress bar stuck at 99%, and if you are using Visual Studio, you have to **uncheck** 'Enable Browser Link' option. This will solve the incomplete progress bar issue.

[image]

Comment: @NevilleKatila Happy coding :)

Comment: I assume this is because it creates a WebSocket connection, which is a request that doesn't really "complete", but remains active.

Answer (score 2):

Please check that you add all the file properly, like jquery.js or theme.atom.css or pace.js etc...